# I have a REST service,on whose success as well as on error in both the scenarios another REST call is to be made in angular

Tags: angular

My question is calling another http call from error body is correct or there is some other approach, as in my code I have already implemented and it is working but wanted to ask the recommended way

```
          `this.httpService.somefunction('get', url, function (data) {

             //one more http call   


         }, function (err) {

             //one more http call here as well on error

        }, {});`
```

Comment: I am also attaching a link in case for more details https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7fee638db5b5204ca9ea1dd8989b5b25

Answer (score 0):

If you use rxjs `Observable`, search for `finally` method. That one could be executed after any result returned from first request.

Comment: Hi @A. Tim thankyou , I am using rxjs/Observable but the http service which I am using in my service file has  this.http.get(url, { headers: headers }).toPromise().then(success).catch(error), could you help me on chat if possible